# Angular Template Check Error while using Union Type of TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

#### Interface

```
export interface Review {
  _id: string;
  locationId: string;
  rating: number;
  review: string;
  userId: user | string;
}

interface user {
  _id: string;
  profile_pic: string;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
}
```

#### TS File

```
reviews: Review[];
```

#### Using in Template

```
<div *ngFor="let review of reviews">
  <img [src]="review.userId.profile_pic">
</div>
```

#### Error

```
Identifier 'profile_pic' is not defined. 'string | user' does not contain such a member
```

The Error above is visible in my IDE. But Works fine while I run it on browser.

Comment: why is userId is this way? `userId: user | string;` since your IDE thinks profile_pic doesn't exist coz user is assigned as a string.

Comment: How do I assign multiple types to a property as per my requirement?

Comment: Well, your assignment is correct on a standard notation you used rename your interface to `User` and you can add an? something like `review.userId?.profile_pic` for safe loading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**If you really want to stick with your current schema**, you could use a [custom pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes) to set the type of userID to `user` where you know `myUser` will not be a string. Something like:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
// You will also need to import your `user` interface
@Pipe({name: 'assignUserType'})
export class ExponentialStrengthPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(myUser): User {
        return myUser as User;
    }
}
```

Then you can use this in your template:

```
{{review.userId | assignUserType}}
```

As you might expect, this will error if `myUser` does not satisfy your interface `user`.

**tl;dr - I would use approach 3 at the bottom of my answer.**

As per the comment by [@abhishek-ekaanth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6821441/abhishek-ekaanth), I wouldn't recommend this approach:

```
userId: user | string;
```

Aside from the error, this will **very likely** cause you issues at some point, because there are two different possible paths to the ID of the user, depending on whether `userId` is a string or not.

If there are situations where you might only have a `userId` but not a `user` assigned to a `Review`, you could take one of the following approaches:

**Approach 1**:

Separate `userId` and `user` into two separate properties and make `user` optional:

```
export interface Review {
    _id: string;
    locationId: string;
    rating: number;
    review: string;
    userId: string;
    user?: user;
}
```

If you wanted to avoid repeating `userId` where a `user`, is present you could make `userId` optional too and populate one or the other, but as per my first point, I think this will cause you headaches.

Then in your template you can do:

```
<div *ngFor="let review of reviews">
    <img *ngIf="review.user" [src]="review.user.profile_pic">
</div>
```

Which will only display the pic if `review.user` is populated.

**Approach 2**:

Probably closer you your initial approach:

```
export interface Review {
    _id: string;
    locationId: string;
    rating: number;
    review: string;
    user: user;
}

interface user {
    _id: string;
    profile_pic?: string;
    first_name?: string;
    last_name?: string;
}
```

So where you have only a user ID, `user` would just be:

```
{
    _id: 'myUserID'
}
```

This avoids repeating the user ID in `Review` and has the benefit of a consistent path to the user ID, whether the other properties of `user` are populated or not.

The drawback is the awkwardness of making all the other properties of `user` optional.

You can then do:

```
<div *ngFor="let review of reviews">
    <img *ngIf="review.user.profile_pic" [src]="review.user.profile_pic">
</div>
```

**Approach 3:**

...because good things come in threes - this is the one I would use.

```
export interface Review {
    _id: string;
    locationId: string;
    rating: number;
    review: string;
    user: user;
}

interface user {
    _id: string;
    userProperties?: UserProperties;
}

interface UserProperties {
    profile_pic: string;
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
}
```

And in your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let review of reviews">
    <img *ngIf="review.user.userProperties" [src]="review.user.userProperties.profile_pic">
</div>
```

Comment: Actually I am getting these fields from backend exactly from mongodb. When I display a review sometimes I just want `userId` as a `string` or sometimes I populate the `userId` with some user's schema fields.
AND is my way of asking the question is wrong. how someone voted -1. Please let me know if I can change the way of asking questions.

Comment: You should be able to use a custom pipe in your template to ensure `userID` is correctly typed. Have updated my answer. Still seems like an odd architectural choice though... if possible I'd separate the ID per approach 3 in my answer from the other schema fields and just populate them if you need them.

Comment: Thanks, @MattSaunders for insight. I will make a note of this approach :)